# Why some lines are not called in my onPostExecute()?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm currently confused. Some of the lines I wrote in my onPostExecute() does not get called. Here's my AsyncTask code:

```
public class GuestInfoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int charRead;
                char[] charBuffer = new char[500];  // download 500 characters at a time
                while(true)
                {
                    charRead = inputStreamReader.read(charBuffer);
                    if(charRead <= 0)
                        break;

                    stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(charBuffer), 0, charRead);
                }

                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if(s != null)
            {
                // THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED!
                System.out.println("Successfully retrieved guest info with response: " + s);

                // TODO: parse the data here
                // THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED ALSO!
                System.out.println("TEST: " + s);

                // BUT THIS GETS CALLED
                // alert dialog the response here
                new AlertDialog.Builder(GuestInfoActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Guest Info")
                        .setMessage("Message: " + s)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                        .show();



            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to retrieve guest info! Double check your server address and/or network connection!");
                new AlertDialog.Builder(GuestInfoActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Failed to retrieve guest info! Double check your server address and/or network connection!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                        .show();
            }



            // disable the progressbar after
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I have a `button` that when tapped, executes the above `AsyncTask`. Now when the task finishes, I successfully see the `AlertDialog` on the screen, but not the `printLines` I have. I also tried `Log.i()` but same result.

Why is this so? Is there something wrong on my end? For what it's worth, I'm on Android Studio 1.51 and emulator API 19

EDIT: I think I've narrowed down the culprit. If I type Log.d("tag", "test"), this shows in the log successfully. But if I type Log.d("tag", s), where `s` is the result of the onPostExecute, I do not see it in the logs. It seems there's a problem outputting the onPostExecute result string?

Comment: Possibly your logcat filter level is set to display higher level messages only.

Comment: Clean build your project and run again on your device.

Comment: change `System.out.println()` to `Log.d("tag", "message");` and check again if executes

Comment: It gets called, but outputs somewhere where you don't see

Comment: System.out.println is not supported by every device. Older Android API and/or custom roms doesn´t support it. Maybe other devices too. To be sure, use Log.

Comment: I have edited my original post. I think I've narrowed down the culprit. If I type Log.d("tag", "test"), this shows in the log successfully. But if I type Log.d("tag", s), where s is the result of the onPostExecute, I do not see it in the logs. It seems there's a problem outputting the onPostExecute result string?

Comment: Then You should rework Your question, because the problem is that You get an empty string....

Comment: Can't be an empty string because I output the `s` variable in an AlertDialog in my code and I can successfully see the string there.

Answer (score 2):

The lines you are pointing are `System.out.println` commands. They surely are called, but you don't see them because the string are being displayed in the default system output (`sysout`), which is not the console you see in your Android Studio.

To see those messages in your console (logcat), you can use one of the methods of the `Log` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

So, instead of `System.out.println("TEST: " + s)`, try:

```
Log.i("tag", "TEST: " + s)
```

Remember that `Log.i` is printing messages in the info level, and therefore you need to check if your console (logcat) is showing the messages in that level. Other levels are:

```
Log.v("tag", "TEST: " + s) // VERBOSE
Log.d("tag", "TEST: " + s) // DEBUG
Log.w("tag", "TEST: " + s) // WARNING
Log.e("tag", "TEST: " + s) // ERROR
```

Comment: FWIW, most devices are configured with the `log.redirect-stdio` system property set to true, which redirects `System.out` and `System.err` to logcat with INFO level. OP also said he cannot see `Log.i()` output either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried Log.d and it is showing in my logs now. But I have a follow up question. I tried creating a new function, then passing the AsyncTask string result to the said function, and inside the function Log.d the info. But that does not show up in my logs. Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my original post. I think I've narrowed down the culprit. If I type Log.d("tag", "test"), this shows in the log successfully. But if I type Log.d("tag", s), where `s` is the result of the onPostExecute, I do not see it in the logs. It seems there's a problem outputting the onPostExecute result string?

Comment: Even if the `s` string is empty, you should see the tag. What happens if you write `log.d("tag", "Here is s:" + s)`? Have you tried to debug those lines to ensure that `s` has a value?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure that the `s` is not null and has a value. Because after writing `Log.d`, you can see that I output the `s` in an AlertDialog and I'm able to see its value there. So pretty strange...